# Design of network analyser using usrp b2130 and Gnu radio

Tags: gnuradio

I am newbie to Gnu radio! I have designed basic things like signal generator and FM receiver. Now I want to design a network analyser with USRP B210. Kindly tell me where to start and where to look! If possible give a workspace screenshot.

Comment: What kind of network analyzer do you want to build?

Comment: Vector network analyser

Comment: Vector network analyser to  determine s parameters of an antenna